# How to create SMS sender application on ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Does anyone know how to create a SMS sender application on ASP.Net?

I want to make an application that can be accessed by multiple users at the same time (user can click "send unique code" button on the website to get their own random unique code).

I've tried using a GSMComm library to do  that task, but the GSMComm only can handle one request for send a SMS to user's mobile phone..

Any suggestion? thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement the unique code part by yourself.

I don't know the way GSMComm library implemented but if you have a limitation like this, you can use something like queue or semaphore.

Easiest way is buying service from a pro company and using their API to send SMS